# Neural network implementation to produce a better estimation of the input

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, unsupervised-learning

I have to configure a neural network where I do not have a real 'target dataset', but I would like to produce a better estimation of my input.

The input u is a function of 2 parameters:

u(a,b)=f(a)+g(b)
where f and g are linear functions.

I have as 'training dataset' values of 'u' for given a and b.

My aim is to produce a better estimation of this variable 'u' based on the fact that it should not exceed a maximum error.

Can someone help me with some idea on how to proceed? Should I consider unsupervised NN ?

Thanks for any kind of help!

Comment: That's so informal that i don't understand what you are trying to achieve. As there are 3 close-votes now, you should really edit your question! If a and b are your only params, what to optimize? Where does the error come from? What is F and G? When those are unrestricted functions (which would not make sense), why having this form / 2? Where is ```u``` which you mention? This is really unfit to answer!

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it in a better form. Hope that now the problem is more understandable, please ask me for clarifications!

Comment: @forward Can you provide an example training set. Your question is still unclear.